# JMeter - How to know which request fails?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, loadrunner

In JMeter, let's say in Transaction Controller I have 1 main html request which downloads 15 embedded resources. So during the test if ONE of the 15 request fails, then how can I know which request failed?

Comment: Easy answer.  At the end of the test check the HTTP Error log.   Any 4xx-5xx items will show up here.

Comment: Or, you could just choose to exercise the top level request without pulling the rest of the page assets.  Then you will not have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can see which ONE of the resources has failed by looking at:

1. In GUI mode into [VIEW RESULTS TREE](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) LISTENER, the "Sampler result" tab for the FAILED sampler will show the reason in the RESPONSE MESSAGE
2. If you [run your JMETER test in COMMAND-LINE NON-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) you will be able to see the failure cause IN [.JTL results FILE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Actually I am interested to know that in non-gui mode. ..anyway, in the video why it shows Response code of 200 with Embedded resource download error?